# how to reset mappings in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I recently misconfigured the mappings in symfony by typing in in the console bin/console doctrine:generate:entities /entity/user although there is nothing which needs to be mapped because I use FOS, is there anyway to reset all the mappings because I get mapping exception which says " Class `AppBundle\Entity\User` sub class of `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` is not a valid entity or mapped super class. `reinstallation will be a little bit troublesome because of several configured dependencies which will be lost.`

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cache directory?

Comment: not yet, where can I find it?

Comment: You have to generate/create your user entity yourself. So what has been generated is correct. You should read the documentation of the fos user bundle to get started.

Comment: deleting the cache in dev folder has helped, thanks a lot